# Number of spanning trees using matrix tree theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

$K_n$ denotes the complete graph with $n$ vertices. Show by means of the matrix tree theorem that the number of spanning trees of $K_n$ is $n^{n-2}$.

I did something like this:

$$(D-A)' = \begin{pmatrix} n-1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & \ldots \\ -1 & n-1 & -1 & -1 & \ldots \\ -1 & -1 & n-1 & -1 & \ldots \\ -1 & -1 & -1 & n-1 & \ldots \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

Because it is a complete graph, I assume that $(D - A)'$ will have the above values. Is it correct?
For the next move, I read somewhere that I need to do some kind of transformation to the matrix and compute the minors. But how should the matrix be transformed? And how should the minors be computed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor is found by deleting a row and a column from a matrix. You could delete the top row and the left column to get a minor. It will have the same determinant as any other minor, so you might as well choose this one.

$$M_{11} = \begin{pmatrix} n-1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & \ldots \\ -1 & n-1 & -1 & -1 & \ldots \\ -1 & -1 & n-1 & -1 & \ldots \\ -1 & -1 & -1 & n-1 & \ldots \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

Note that this is an $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix.

The determinant can be shown to be $(n-1)^{n-1}+(n-2)(-1)^{n-2}-(n-1)(n-1)(-1)^{n-2}$